# Why App Engine (Node.js) duplicates logs?

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, logging

### Why third and fourth logs are duplicated?

---

[image]

### I run only one instance:

---

***app.yaml***

```
runtime: nodejs10

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

---

[image: versions screenshot]

### Here is where logs are called:

---

***server.js***
[image: server.js screenshot]

### And here is how the App Engine builds nextjs project (gcp-build) and how it runs it (start)

---

***package.js***
[image]

Comment: This would be a good point to discuss in [Google Groups](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/groups) as well, as Google Groups hosts discussion forums where you're likely to find information like service status updates and release notes and high-level discussions on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about duplication, it had been a bug\feature in Next.js.